# HAProxy: Detect SSL connection contents and then decide to forward it or not

Tags: ssh, ssl, https, haproxy, forwarding

I would like to have a front end with HAProxy on port 443. This front end acts in the following way:

It decrypts the contents of the connection and checks:

1- If the encrypted contents of the connection is ssh, i.e., if the first words of the packets are `SSH-2.0`, then it forwards the decrypted packets to port 22. I assume such a back end looks like this:

```
backend ssh
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    server ssh 127.0.0.1:22
    timeout server 2h
```

2- If the encrypted contents are anything else, then forward the encrypted contents to port 8443, which contains an Apache server with correct SNI keys. If it's a must to include all correct SNI keys for each web address (in order not to look as a man-in-the-middle-attack, could you please tell me how to do that with an example? I have no problem adding all keys to HAProxy.

**Why?** Because I already have apache working on port 443. I would like to move it to some other port without having to rewrite my whole configuration. So I would like to move it to port 8443 for example, and then tell HAProxy, if the connection is not SSH, then just forward everything you get to port 443.

**How do I write such a front end + back ends? Please assist.**

I current have the following front end as a starting point:

```
frontend ssl
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /home/myuser/SSL/certs.pem no-sslv3   #decrypts the connection with the keys certs.pem
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if HTTP
    acl client_attempts_ssh payload(0,7) -m bin 5353482d322e30   #if the decrypted information starts with SSH-2.0

    use_backend ssh if client_attempts_ssh   #forward to SSH if condition client_attempts_ssh is satisfied.
    use_backend forwardToApache if !client_attempts_ssh
```

Please ask if you require any additional details.

Thank you.

Comment: There's so many weird things with what you're trying to do, but I'll leave those for now. For starters, can you post your full config, and what's actually wrong/not working.

Comment: @GregL My initial config is in this link http://blog.chmd.fr/ssh-over-ssl-episode-4-a-haproxy-based-configuration.html . The difference with my situation is that I have port 443 already in use by apache, meaning that I have to move apache to some other port. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: That links explains most of the weirdness I was seeing. It might be worth updating your question to include some of the details from it, so that it's more clear. The question still remains: what's not working?

Comment: Wouldn't [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) solve your problems?

Comment: @GregL I will edit the question later as I'm currently in the train station. My problem is that I don't know how to write front and back ends that do the forwarding I explained.

Comment: `My problem is that I don't know how to write front and back ends that do the forwarding I explained.` That article you linked seems to do a pretty good job.. Besides, we at SF expect that you have at least tried something, and can provide us with *what* you tried, and what's not working. Simply saying "I don't know how to do it" doesn't tend to be well received here.

Comment: @hbruijn sslh does only forwarding. I want my ssh connection to be encrypted inside ssl so that it's undetectable. A good firewall will find out what sslh is trying to do.

Comment: @GregL What I tried is to just use that code from that website directly, but then it conflicts with apache and haproxy gives an error that it cannot bind to port 443. I don't know how to proceed in modifying the config file to the correct form requires to do what I need. I need some expert's advice on the whole matter and whether it could work in an easy way without generating a man-in-the-middle-attack problem.

Comment: `I need some expert's advice on the whole matter`. No, you want us to do it for you. However, my advice, as an "expert", is to try things until a) it works, or b) you have shown some effort and can come back to us with an *actual* problem.

Comment: Isn't your situation just like the one in the link, only that you want the local apache on 8443 while it's at 80 in the example?

Comment: @GregL No I don't want you to do it for me. Please try to be more understanding and less judgmental. For example, you as an expert, did you answer my question on whether this will create a man-in-the-middle-attack problem?

Comment: @beerserc interestingly not. The difference is that in the link, the data is decrypted and forwarded to http as nonencrypted http, but I need tcp forwarding before Decryption if the decrypted data does not contain ssh-2.0 string in its beginning.

Comment: so you want to kind of fork the encrypted data, decrypt it to check if it's ssh, and if not, send the non-decrypted data on towards apache, did I get that right?

Comment: but in any case, if you want haproxy on port 443 you need to first move apache to someportelse, like 8443

Comment: @beerserc yes exactly. I want to fork it the way you described it. Of course, changing the port is a given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SNI first, selecting

```
site1.domain.com, 
site2.domain.com,
```

or

```
ssh.domain.com
```

and only if ssh.domain.com is selected you decrypt, do the ssh magic and send it to a local webserver unencrypted, assuming this is supposed to look like regular https traffic, but doesn't contain sensitive information inside the https content, because this is handled by site1 and site2.

Comment: Just combine your link and http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/04/13/enhanced-ssl-load-balancing-with-server-name-indication-sni-tls-extension/